# What precautions should I take with .debs I find on the internet?

Tags: package-management, security, deb

So I was browsing the web the other day, and I came across a few places that wanted me to download `.deb` files - and since those are installed by root (and as such have the "powers" and capabilities of root), I wasn't sure about that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Things to consider:

- How well known is the site? For example, was it a random blog covered in ads, was it a random user on some forum, or was it a well known, respected site?
- What does it claim to install? For example, does it claim to install a kernel or a iconset, but is it only 1MB big?
- How "important" is it that you have the contents of this `.deb`?

Ways to test things securely:

I use [`arkose`](http://launchpad.net/arkose) ([its in the standard repos](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/arkose) [image: Install arkose]
) sandboxing with my debs (and other things) - use it something like this:

`sudo arkose -n -c "cd $PWD; $SHELL"`

What that does it give me a "sandbox" (otherwise known as "YAY I CAN SCREW UP!") with copy-on-write access to everything on my computer, including my home directory - so if the nasty nasty `.deb` does `sudo rm -rf /*`, **I DON'T LOSE ANY DATA!**

Another thing that isn't stressed enough is ***MAKE BACKUPS***. Those are extremely helpful, and [we have many questions on the topic.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/backup)

In short, just make sure you think about it, and don't just download a random deb and install it.

Comment: Open the `.deb` with File roller see what's inside. Though i must say i downloaded a random deb from a random user on a random thread on the Ubuntu forums to fix my issues with my printer, it worked.

Answer (score 20):

If you are downloading a package from untrusted or questionable sources, be paranoid. On popular forums like ubuntuforums.org, if a user makes his first post containing only of a short text like "install this, works for me!", followed by a link, be careful with that link and/ or instructions.

Don't use binary packages if possible, especially from untrusted sources. Get the source (for official Ubuntu packages, this can be done with `apt-get source package-name`) and have a look at it.

If the package in question is small, it may be worth analysing it. I prefer to use the terminal for that because I then have fast access to other powerful command-line tools like `ls`, `find`, `file`, `less`, `vim`, `grep`, `sed`, `dpkg` and lots others. Make use of tab-completion (i.e. hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete commands and filenames), it really saves time!

To download a .deb file, you can use the browser, but copying the link and then use `wget` is faster since you can already experiment with it.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo && cd /tmp/foo
$ wget http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nvidia-common/nvidia-common_0.2.35_amd64.deb
```

Next, it's time to check the file itself. `less` (through `lesspipe`) can provide a quick overview of the file contents. Arrow keys, page up/down, home/end can be useful for navigating, <kbd>Q</kbd> quits the program.

```
$ less nvidia-common_0.2.35_amd64.deb
nvidia-common_0.2.35_amd64.deb:
 new debian package, version 2.0.
 size 10802 bytes: control archive= 1877 bytes.
     197 bytes,    11 lines   *  config               #!/bin/sh
     703 bytes,    16 lines      control              
     741 bytes,    10 lines      md5sums              
     163 bytes,     9 lines   *  postinst             #!/bin/sh
     206 bytes,     8 lines   *  postrm               #!/bin/sh
     827 bytes,    38 lines   *  preinst              #!/bin/sh
     263 bytes,    14 lines   *  prerm                #!/bin/sh
     365 bytes,    12 lines      templates            
 Package: nvidia-common
 Version: 1:0.2.35
 Architecture: amd64
 Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
 Installed-Size: 156
 Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2)
 Depends: python2.7 | python2.6, python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2), python (<< 2.8), debconf (>= 0.5.00) | debconf-2.0, pciutils, python-apt
 Conflicts: nvidia-180-modaliases, nvidia-185-modaliases, nvidia-current-modaliases
 Replaces: nvidia-180-modaliases, nvidia-185-modaliases, nvidia-current-modaliases
 Section: admin
 Priority: optional
 Description: Find obsolete NVIDIA drivers
  This package will find obsolete NVIDIA drivers in use,
  detect the hardware and recommend the most appropriate
  driver.
 Python-Version: 2.6, 2.7

*** Contents:
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2011-09-07 11:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2011-09-07 11:06 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2011-09-07 11:06 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2011-09-07 11:06 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2011-09-07 11:06 ./usr/share/doc/nvidia-common/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1174 2011-09-07 11:07 ./usr/share/doc/nvidia-common/changelog.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       466 2011-06-24 14:45 ./usr/share/doc/nvidia-common/copyright
...
```

After this, you get an overview of the package dependencies and what kind of files it possibly contains. Time to extract the files and analyse the contents using [`dpkg-deb`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=dpkg-deb). The first command extracts the file tree in a newly created directory `fs`, the second one extracts it to `DEBIAN` because no other target is specified:

```
$ dpkg-deb -x nvidia-common_0.2.35_amd64.deb fs
$ dpkg-deb -e nvidia-common_0.2.35_amd64.deb
```

We'll use `less` again to analyze the contents of the maintainer scripts (i.e. the files that will be used/ run during installation (and removal). `prerm`, `preinst`, `postrm`, `postinst` are scripts run before/after removal/installation which are the most important files to analyse. Use `:n` and `:p` to switch between the files. By pressing `=`, you get the current file name and line number as well as the number of files that are in the list.

```
$ less DEBIAN/*
```

If the package scripts look sane, it's time to analyse the installed contents (use tab-completion). For shell scripts and interpreted scripts (like Python), analysis is easier (assuming that you're known with the language).

```
$ less fs/usr/bin/nvidia-detector    # fs<TAB><TAB>/usr/ <TAB><TAB>bin ...
$ less fs/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install
$ ls -la fs/usr/lib     # quickly check the directory contents, my memory is weak
drwxr-xr-x 5 peter peter 100 2011-09-07 11:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 peter peter 100 2011-09-07 11:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 peter peter  60 2011-09-07 11:06 nvidia
drwxr-xr-x 3 peter peter  60 2011-09-07 11:06 python2.6
drwxr-xr-x 3 peter peter  60 2011-09-07 11:06 python2.7
$ # I conclude: python2.6 is not a symlink to python2.7
$ less fs/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/NvidiaDetector/*
press 'v' to open an editor (e.g. nano, vim) to get syntax highlighting if preferable
```

Pay special attention to configuration files, especially if they are using directories like `/etc/init` (for startup scripts) or `/etc/modprobe.d` (options for loading kernel modules).

For binaries, `ldd` can give an idea what a program could be used for. The below program looks like a graphical program that uses OpenGL.

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/glxgears
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7d3ff000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fa2ead11000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa2eaa8d000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fa2ea754000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa2ea3b5000)
...
```

After you are sure that the package looks valid, you can go on install it in VirtualBox booting off a Live CD and use `ps aux`, `top`, `strace -f -o logfile.txt programname` for further analysis.