# How can I analyze this debian package before installing it?

Tags: package-management

I'm looking at [this debian package](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/dist/jetty-deb/8.1.0.v20120127/)

Before installing it, I'm curious about how much information I can get just by analyzing the debian package.

I would love to know exactly what is going to be installed and where.

is this possible?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/97667/what-precautions-should-i-take-with-debs-i-find-on-the-internet -- or search the site for `deb security`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want this from the commandline, use dpkg-deb:

```
dpkg-deb --extract some-package.deb /directory/to/unpack

dpkg-deb --control some-package.deb /directory/to/unpack/DEBIAN
```

This should leave a directory structure similar to what you'd be able to see in gdebi.

Comment: but what if it installs to /etc/default?  will it be forced to create that in /directory/to/unpack?

Comment: No, it creates the directories it needs, so in this case `/directory/to/unpack/etc` will be created. Try it, it's harmless! Just don't point it at your root, i.e. don't `dpkg-deb --extract pack.deb /`

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is very possible.

Install Gdebi

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

[image: gdebi screenshot]

Open Gdebi, then open the Debian package from **File > Open**.

Comment: would this work from the command line?

Comment: @Blankman: no, sorry.