# How can I install Inkscape from BZR?

Tags: compiling, bazaar, inkscape

In order to get the latest version of Inkscape, one has to use BZR.

How can I install inkscape using BZR and properly install it on my System?.

Detailed step by step guide would be preferable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First install the build dependencies, you can do this simply by asking apt for the dependencies, first you need to make sure the source code section of software sources is set up:

- [How do I enable the source code repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158871/how-do-i-enable-the-source-code-repositories)

Then install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep inkscape
```

Then you want to pull the source, in this case we don' t need the entire history for the project so we'll just do a lightweight checkout, this can still take a while:

```
bzr co --lightweight lp:inkscape
```

Then we need to cd into the directory and build it

```
cd inkscape
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This will build Inkscape and install it into `/usr/local/bin/inkscape` by default.

Comment: Thank you very much Jorge, however i get an error when attempting to get the dependencies see my edit.

Comment: @UriHerrera: the error you pasted above was due to you typing `inkspace`, rather than `inkscape`

Comment: OMG.. feel like a noob.. Does this replace the installed inkscape (if it is installed) with the version from bzr?.

Comment: It should, launch it in a terminal and check the version #

Answer (score 8):

#### Warning: Third party PPA, proceed with caution. More details on [that here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97667/what-precautions-should-i-take-with-debs-i-find-on-the-internet).

---

I just did a quick search on Launchpad, and discovered [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecafuego/+archive/inkscape), which appears to have daily builds of inkscape available. Instructions on [how to add the PPA are available here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them), the PPA you want to add is `ppa:cafuego/inkscape`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised i didn't found it. This is awesome!.